# Как спарсить HTML таблицы в файл CSV?

Tags: html, python, парсер

Есть [сайт с множеством компаний](https://www.investing.com/equities/). Если открыть любую из них, допустим Alphabet, и после открыть вкладки *financials*, и далее [balance sheet](https://www.investing.com/equities/google-inc-c-balance-sheet), то появляется таблица. Такая таблица есть у каждой компании.

Как можно парсить такие таблицы, просто меняя ссылку на компанию?

Пример таблицы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данные необходимо выгружать в CSV файл.

Вот что есть на данный момент, но я не понимаю, как привести выходные данные к должному виду и выгрузить их в файл:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import pandas as pd
    
data = []
site= "https://www.investing.com/equities/ebay-inc-balance-sheet"
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req = Request(site,headers=hdr)
page = urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
table = soup.find("table",{"class": "genTbl reportTbl"})
td_list = []

line = soup.find("table",{"class": "genTbl reportTbl"}).find('tbody').find_all('tr')
for row in line:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
    data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])

print(data)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.investing.com/equities/google-inc-c-balance-sheet'

header = {
  "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36",
  "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=header)

periods = pd.read_html(r.text, match='Period\s+Ending.*')[0].columns[1:]

dfs = pd.read_html(r.text, match='Total\s+.*')

for i,df in enumerate(dfs):
    (df.set_index(df.columns[0])
       .set_axis(periods, axis=1, inplace=False)
       .to_csv(rf'c:\temp\tab_{i:02d}.csv'))
```

Comment: появляется ошибка ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 4 elements, new values have 45 elements

Comment: @Shared, получилось?

Comment: не, яж написал выше, ошибка ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 4 elements, new values have 45 elements

Comment: @Shared, я запускаю весь код из ответа "как есть" под Pandas 0.24.1 - все работает... Какая у вас версия Pandas?

Comment: обновил pandas, появилось 4 таблицы, только они без разделителей. А нельзя всю информацию в 1 таблицу сохранять?

Comment: @Shared, наверное можно, но скорее всего придется ручками парсить...

Comment: Вы не сможете сделать?

Comment: @Shared, а разве в файле "tab_00.csv" - не то, что вам нужно?

Comment: Да, там по моему все что нужно, но опять же можно как-то по ячейкам разбить информацию?

Comment: @Shared, если пропустить "длинные" строки, то получится то что вы хотите получить или нет?

Comment: что вы имеете ввиду под пропустить?

Comment: @Shared, я имею ввиду [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/947618/211923)

Answer (score 2):

Еще один вариант решения:

```
url = 'https://www.investing.com/equities/google-inc-c-balance-sheet'

header = {
  "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36",
  "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=header)

df = pd.read_html(r.text, match='Total\s+.*')[0]

df = df.rename(columns={'Period Ending:':'Name'})

res = df.loc[df['Name'].str.len() < 100]
# save to CSV
res.to_csv(r'c:\path\to\result.csv', sep=',', index=False)
# save to Excel
res.to_excel(r'c:\path\to\result.xlsx', index=False)
```

Результат:

```
In [50]: pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 20)

In [51]: res
Out[51]:
                                        Name 201831/12 201830/09 201830/06 201831/03
0                       Total Current Assets    135676    129702    124157    123761
2            Cash and Short Term Investments    109140    106416    102254    102885
3                                       Cash         -         -         -         -
4                         Cash & Equivalents     16701     13443     14148     12658
5                     Short Term Investments     92439     92973     88106     90227
6                     Total Receivables, Net     21193     18067     17244     16814
7          Accounts Receivables - Trade, Net     20838     17897     17043     16777
8                            Total Inventory      1107      1212       698       636
9                           Prepaid Expenses      3723      3775      3540      3240
10               Other Current Assets, Total       513       232       421       186
..                                       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...
43                       Common Stock, Total       0.7       0.7       0.7      0.69
44                Additional Paid-In Capital   45048.3   43110.3   42242.3  41486.31
45   Retained Earnings (Accumulated Deficit)    134885    128405    121282    120008
46                   Treasury Stock - Common         -         -         -         -
47                       ESOP Debt Guarantee         -         -         -         -
48                    Unrealized Gain (Loss)      -688      -279      -188       -34
49                       Other Equity, Total     -1618     -1397     -1337      -636
50  Total Liabilities & Shareholders' Equity    232792    221538    211610    206935
51           Total Common Shares Outstanding    695.56    695.96    695.95    694.95
52        Total Preferred Shares Outstanding         -         -         -         -

[48 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: Да, то что нужно, как теперь это в файл выгрузить?

Comment: @Shared, дополнил ответ...

Comment: Спасибо за такую помощь) Но он все же опять без разделителей, весь текст в 1 ячейке

Comment: @Shared, у меня с разделителями... Как вы проверяли?

Comment: открыл файл в excel, добавил картинку в вопрос как выглядят данные

Comment: Посмотрите внимательно обновленный ответ - там уже создается полноценный Excel файл. Если хотите открывать CSV в Excel, то используйте `;` в качестве разделителя